# Unable to locate element in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to locate element
which is having html Code:

```
<td align="center" colspan="2">OTP : 6363 </td>
```

& html tag starts from `td/`
I want to get the text over it so,
I tried by writing code `driver.findelement(By.id("otp")).getText();`

Comment: the html code is: <td align="center" colspan="2">OTP : 6363 </td>

Comment: **otp** is not id actually.

Comment: Try this if you have only 1 TD : `driver.findElement(By.tagName("td")).gettext(); `

Comment: try `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(text(), 'OTP :')]")).getText();`

Comment: Yeah bt html code is like this i am not getting how i will identify that element

Comment: I tried String otp=driver.findElement(By.tagName("td")).getText();

Comment: but it printing other text i want the the OTP number i.e 6363

Comment: Thank you second onw worked for me but i want only the number its coming entire OTP: 6363 but iwant only 6363 as i have to paste this number in other text box

Comment: So you want only 6363 from OTP: 6363 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try your tag name. Example :-

```
driver.findElement(By.tagName("td")).getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

As said otp is not id. Its text that would display in that td cell.

For example id will display like this

```
<input **id="search"** class="test" type="text"/>
```

so you can try with other locators may by using  xpath, cssSelector etc..

for example, xpath with taking consideration as OTP text will display, then

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(text(), 'OTP :')]")).getText();
```

You can also use xpath=//td or By.tagName("td") but mostly more number of td elements will be present in page, so it may not fetch you required unique element.

Please provide total DOM HTML code to suggest locators..

Thanks

Comment: hi this is the total html code:<form method="POST" action="getOTP.jsp">
<table align="center">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" colspan="2">OTP : 6840 </td>

Comment: so i hope you can use xpath=//form[@method='POST']/table/tbody/tr[3]/td to get required text, you can use string splitter..  
  String text= "OTP:6363";
  String[] parts = text.split(":");
  String part1 = parts[0]; // OTP
  String part2 = parts[1]; //6363

Comment: sorry i dint get you shall i use the xpath but this prints OTP: 6840 but i want only 6840 please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to get output as per your requirement :

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.tagName("td")).getText();
text = text.replaceAll("\\D+","");
System.out.println(text);
```

In code , First of all getting text of TD tag, Then removing all non-digits and then getting only digit values.